# REST web application: what is the role of XML/JSON?

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, service

I am currently learning about `REST` applications, and particularly `Java` implementations of REST.

I am unsure of what role `JSON` or `XML` plays in in REST?

An **example** to show  my current understanding:

1. User clicks a button on front end.
2. User is re-directed to a URL e.g /user/{userid}
3. Java method in service class calls repository (e.g. Crud Repository) class to retrieve data
4. Repository pulls data from db (e.g. about that specific user)
5. data passed back to service class and is then shown on the UI to user.

Where does `JSON` or `XML` fit into this process?

Comment: `Service class`  then pass the result to `controller` and `controller`  will convert the data to `JSON` and passed to `View`

Comment: Ok so basically either JSON or XML is needed to actually show it to the user?

Comment: Wait i will explain as an answer,. Hope that will make you clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we divide your 5th step... 
1) data is returned from service in a certain format
2) UI receives it in that format and display it on the screen.
This format is XML or JSON or even plain text. This is the Accept type you mention when making a call from UI, and set the response header in service.

JSON stands for Javascript Object notation, hence if the response is in JSON format, you can directly use it as a javascript variable by just parsing it using JSON.parse. The Accept type is actually depends on your requirement. For most of the cases JSON is preferred, as it is easily converted to JS object.

Comment: this is v helpful. Just to confirm: data is passed back from the repository generally as a java object? how then is this java object converted to JSON?

Comment: if you are using Spring, then you can find JSON view resolvers for doing these. You can follow http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/ -- it is a very good example project. You can find JSON, XML, text even pdf and xls resolvers to form your response. Hope it will help you.

Comment: ok ill look into it, but im trying to understand "under the hood" at the minute. Is the following correct? :  1. the service class passes back a Java object (POJO)? 2. The Java object is used to create a JSON object 3. The JSON object is used to display data on screen to the user?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. In the front end you wont receive the JSON object directly. It will be a string only which you need to parse it to a JS object. Run the example, check the request response, you will have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It is the format that the data is returned from the service to the front end.

Comment: Thanks, could you please update my example I gave to show my JSON/XML is used?

Answer (score 1):

The transmission of data between the front end and the api is done in *JSON* and/or *XML*.

So, simplisticly...
    the user asks for some data, through some web page, and the web page asks the RESTful API for the specific data, the api sends the web page the data as *JSON*, then the web page manipulates that and displays it or does whatever it needs to do with that data.

That is a general way to describe its role

Comment: ok thanks, so JSON has nothing to do with retrieving from the DB? can you please edit my example above to show how JSON would fit in there?

Comment: Correct. the api you are talking to could use a database to store information, but it communicates primarily through json and xml

Comment: Please show answer as a sequence to help understanding>

Answer (score 1):

A Method inside the controller is shown below which give json response

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getSomething(HttpServletRequest req) 
    {

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
        Collection someList = new ArrayList();

        someList = someService.getsomeList(req); // here you get the response from service class to controller
        Iterator iter = categoryList.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) // iterate the colleection
        {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                SomeClass someObj = (SomeClass) iter.next();
                jsonObj.put("name", someObj.getName());
                jsonArr.put(jsonObj);
        }

        return jsonArr.toString(); // return jsonstring as response
    }
```

This is how it can be processed in view (Say `JSP`). Here an ajax call made to controller and response set to the field in the page.

```
$.ajax({
                        url : "getSomething.htm", //request send to controller
                        type : "POST",
                        data : {
                            'someData' : data
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            var arr = JSON.parse(data);
                            response($.map(arr, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    value : item.name, //setting the value to the view 

                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, so : 1. the service class passes back a Java object (POJO)? 2. The Java object is used to create a JSON object 3. The JSON object is used to display data on screen to the user?

Comment: @java123999 exactly . If that explains your question choose as right answer

Comment: Just want to clarify something else: the Java handler class returns a resonse (e.g. OK) with json data to the view? this is how the data is then shown on the view?

Comment: @java123999 am not getting your question ! could you please clarify!

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, in your example JSON/XML fits at the end of the chain (almost), when data is returned from the server to the client.

Think of JSON and XML (and other formats) as a type of box. Some boxes are made of plastic, some are made of cardboard since they serve different purposes.

JSON/XML are types of "boxes" for the data you are sending/requesting to/from the server.

In your example:

- User clicks a button on front end.
- User is re-directed to a URL e.g /user/{userid}
- Java method in service class calls repository (e.g. Crud Repository) class to retrieve data
- Repository pulls data from db (e.g. about that specific user)
- Data from DB is "translated" from the server's data format ("type of box") into a more common format (like JSON or XML)
- Data in JSON/XML format is sent to the front-end for displaying purposes

Think of it this way: if there wasn't a common format for people/systems to refer to, then if you query an Oracle database you would need to be able to understand that format. If you then had to query a Sybase database, then you would need to be able to understand that as well.

To solve this, you can pick a "common" format (a box that it's easier to fit in more trucks, as opposed to a box that can only be transported by a specific type of truck) and thus make it easier to "transport" that data around.

So in essence, JSON/XML is just a way of representing data, and as such it can be used to represent data that was originally in other "hard to read" format and make it easier to read or work with.

For example by returning your DB objects as JSON you can display them in a web page because most web page frameworks understand JSON as opposed to very few of them natively understanding Oracle/Sybase formats (there are drivers to do this but it is beyond the scope of this toy example).

You can also use it to communicate with other servers that also understand JSON (like third-party APIs for example) and thus if servers A and B have different data representations (internally one is Oracle backed and the other is Sybase backed) they can still talk to each other using a "common" format like JSON.